# Android: Display.getRotation();

Tags: android, rotation, screen

I have a problem and it is really doing my head in. All I want to do is a very simple task, determine the rotation of the screen. Now Display.getRotation() does exactly this.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29

However when I try to use it I just get "The method getRotation() is undefined for the type Display" and Eclipse tells me to change it to the deprecated function getOrientation() which will not work for what I need because it only returns Landscape/Portrait, not 0/90/180/270.

Does anyone have an idea why this might not be working?

Comment: Did you import Display? Are you using the latest version of the Android SDK?

Comment: Display is imported, and I'm using 2.1 Update 1. So not the very latest but the most common found on handsets.

Answer (score 4):

Display.getRotation() is only available as of API8 (Froyo / 2.2). Your app project probably specifies an earlier API level.

> public int getRotation ()                                       Since: API Level 8

Answer (score 0):

Use getOrientation() instead.  The two functions seem to be identical; I have no idea why they deprecated getOrientation in 2.2.

Comment: This is why: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html. They are not actually the same.