# Android studio 2 migration

Tags: android, android-studio

I am experimenting with the new android studio IDE, and followed the instructions for exporting my old eclipse project and importing it to android studio.  The project ran beautiful before but from android studio it crashes on launch:

```
414/?                              E/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Display.getRotation, referenced from method com.eliddell.AR.ARLaunch.onCreate
05-17 10:45:04.315      414-414/?                              W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 31: Landroid/view/Display;.getRotation ()I
05-17 10:45:04.315      414-414/?                              W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x6e at 0x0029
05-17 10:45:04.315      414-414/?                              W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejected Lcom/eliddell/AR/ARLaunch;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
05-17 10:45:04.315      414-414/?                              W/dalvikvm: Verifier rejected class Lcom/eliddell/AR/ARLaunch;
05-17 10:45:04.315      414-414/?                              W/dalvikvm: Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/eliddell/AR/ARLaunch;)
05-17 10:45:04.315      414-414/?                              D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-17 10:45:04.315      414-414/?                              W/dalvikvm: threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
05-17 10:45:04.315      414-414/?                              E/AndroidRuntime: Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-17 10:45:04.325      414-414/?                              E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.VerifyError: com.eliddell.AR.ARLaunch
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1472)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 10:45:04.325        79-83/system_process                 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 414 SIG: 3
05-17 10:45:04.325      414-417/?                              I/dalvikvm: threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
05-17 10:45:04.335      414-417/?                              E/dalvikvm: Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
05-17 10:45:08.105      414-414/?                              I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 414 SIG: 9
05-17 10:45:08.105        79-84/system_process                 I/ActivityManager: Process com.eliddell.AR (pid 414) has died.
05-17 10:45:08.165        79-84/system_process                 W/UsageStats: Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.eliddell.AR
05-17 10:45:08.245        79-85/system_process                 W/InputManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43864b20
```

any ideas as to whats wrong?  or how i can revert my old project back to eclipse

Comment: why Android Studio 2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Display.getRotation();](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023116/android-display-getrotation)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Target API level, the getRotation method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation() is only available in API 8 and above.

This can be found in File > Project Structure:

[image: proj struc]